# How can I identify an empty window?

Tags: unity, window

**Background:**

On start-up, I have this empty window showing up.

**Screenshot:**

[image: Empty window]

**Question:**

How can I identify what produces this empty window and how can I remove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In far most cases, opening a terminal window, run the command

```
xprop WM_CLASS
```

..and subsequently click on the window will give you sufficient information on the process that owns the window.

***If not***, run the command (assuming you have `wmctrl` installed):

```
wmctrl -lp
```

Make an educated guess on the window from the list, copy the string in third column (its pid) and run:

```
ps -p 1337 -o comm=
```

where `1337` is the pid you just copied. The output will be the process that owns the window.

***If you cannot use the terminal***

..You could keep a log file, keeping track of:

- appearing new windows ("NEW")
- closing windows ("OUT")
- the pid new windows belong to and the application, as it appears in the output of `ps -e`
- the time of appearing/closing

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time

#---set the path to the log file below
logfile = "window_log"
#---

# clear the file from previous runs
open(logfile, "wt").write("")

def get_wlist():
    try:
        return subprocess.check_output(["wmctrl", "-lp"]).decode("utf-8").strip()
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        pass

def get_wids(currlist):
    return [l.split()[0] for l in currlist.splitlines()]

def stamp(s):
    t = time.ctime()
    return (len(t)*"-")+"\n"+s+" "+t+("\n"+len(t)*"-")

def update_log(data):
    with open(logfile, "a+") as log:
        for l in data:
            log.write(str(l)+"\n")
        log.write("\n")

while True:
    # wait until the desktop is ready to run wmctrl
    wdata1 = get_wlist()
    if wdata1:
        break
    time.sleep(1)

# and then...
wlist1 = get_wids(wdata1)

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    wdata2 = get_wlist()
    if wdata2:
        wlist2 = get_wids(wdata2)
        new = [w for w in wlist2 if not w in wlist1]
        for item in new:
            tstamp = stamp("NEW")
            line = wdata2.splitlines()[wlist2.index(item)]
            pid = line.split()[2]
            match = [p for p in subprocess.check_output(
                ["ps", "-e"]
                ).decode("utf-8").splitlines()\
                     if pid in p][0]
            update_log([tstamp, line, match])
        out = [w for w in wlist1 if not w in wlist2]
        for item in out:
            tstamp = stamp("OUT")
            line = wdata1.splitlines()[wlist1.index(item)]
            pid = line.split()[2]
            update_log([tstamp, line])
        wlist1 = wlist2; wdata1 = wdata2
```

- Make sure `wmctrl` is installed

  ```
  sudo apt-get install wmctrl
  ```
- Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `logwindows.py`
- Set the path to the log file in the head of the script
- Run the script by the command:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/logwindows.py
  ```
- If necessary, add it to startup applications if the window only appears shortly after startup

The script produces a log file like:

```
------------------------
NEW Tue Oct  4 17:14:12 2016
------------------------
0x04400007  0 8427   jacob-System-Product-Name Ubuntu
 8427 ?        00:00:01 apport-gtk

------------------------
NEW Tue Oct  4 17:14:28 2016
------------------------
0x04e00084  0 8530   jacob-System-Product-Name Niet-opgeslagen document 1 - gedit
 8530 ?        00:00:00 gedit

------------------------
NEW Tue Oct  4 17:14:31 2016
------------------------
0x0108deb3  0 2013   jacob-System-Product-Name Persoonlijke map
 2013 ?        00:04:20 nautilus

------------------------
NEW Tue Oct  4 17:14:39 2016
------------------------
0x05200085  0 0                            N/A QLE Quicklist Editor
    1 ?        00:00:02 systemd

------------------------
OUT Tue Oct  4 17:14:55 2016
------------------------
0x05200085  0 0                            N/A QLE Quicklist Editor
```

Since you cannot control the time the window appears, but you *can* control the time it closes, *this* should give you sufficient information on the window in any situation.

Comment: `wmctrl: invalid option -- 'P'`

Comment: @orschiro fixed a typo...

Comment: Thank you! [Any of these](https://gist.github.com/orschiro/80b66425456f7a135685845941145427) are suspicious to produce the empty window?

Comment: @orschiro nor sure.. what was the output of xprop?

Comment: I cannot run `xprop` because it requires me to open a terminal window and as soon as I open a terminal window, I no longer see the empty window.

Comment: When I was already running a number of applications, including Chrome. The problem I see is that I need to have at least one open terminal window to run the commands. However, as soon as I have one terminal window open, I can no longer see and access the empty window in the top left.

Comment: @orschiro see updated answer.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! I will run this on startup. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Answering the first half of your question `How can I identify what produces this empty window`, with the window open, open the Terminal and type `xlsclients`:

```
dell  bamfdaemon
dell  ibus-ui-gtk3
dell  ibus-x11
dell  unity-settings-daemon
dell  unity-panel-service
dell  indicator-printers-service
dell  indicator-keyboard-service
dell  unity-fallback-mount-helper
dell  polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1
dell  nm-applet
dell  gnome-software
dell  nautilus
dell  compiz
dell  telepathy-indicator
dell  gnome-terminal-server
dell  update-notifier
dell  notify-osd
dell  hud-service
dell  google-chrome-stable
dell  conky
```

Then close the window and run `xlsclients` again. The process running the window will be the one(s) on the first list but not on the second.

Finding the process name is the first step to stopping it.

HTH.